# Add Class to an Element If It's Sibling Has A Specific Class

Tags: javascript

I am trying to track when a header element contains a specific class or not. The header gets hidden based on scroll down and appears based on scroll up. Several classes get applied to the header during this time period of scrolling up or down. I need the sibling (#main) of header to get a class (scroll-down) added only when the specific class (is-fixed) is applied on the header. Below is the script...

```js
const header = document.querySelector("header");
let lastScroll = 0;

const throttle = (func, time = 100) => {
  let lastTime = 0;
  return () => {
    const now = new Date();
    if (now - lastTime >= time) {
      func();
      time = now;
    }
  };
};

const validateHeader = () => {
  const windowY = window.scrollY;
  const windowH = window.innerHeight;
  if (windowY > windowH) {
    // We passed the first section, set a toggable class
    header.classList.add("is-fixed");
    // Determine is we ready to animate
    if (windowY > windowH + 40) {
      header.classList.add("can-animate");
      if (windowY < lastScroll) {
        // Determine if we scrolling up
        header.classList.add("scroll-up");
      } else {
        header.classList.remove("scroll-up");
      }
    } else {
      header.classList.remove("scroll-up");
    }
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("is-fixed", "can-animate");
  }
  lastScroll = windowY;
};

window.addEventListener("scroll", throttle(validateHeader, 100));
```

```html
<body>
  <header id="header" class="fixed-top">stuff</header>
  <section>stuff</section>
  <section>stuff</section>
  <main id="main" class="components">stuff</main>
</body>
```

**--UPDATE--**

I edited a couple lines to add or remove a class on #main only when #header gets a specific class... (the purpose is adjusting the position of a side menu (in main) when the header gets hidden/shown).

```
  const header = document.querySelector("header");
  let lastScroll = 0;
  const throttle = (func, time = 100) => {
    let lastTime = 0;
    return () => {
      const now = new Date();
      if (now - lastTime >= time) {
        func();
        time = now;
      }
    };
  };
  const validateHeader = () => {
    const windowY = window.scrollY;
    const windowH = window.innerHeight;
    if (windowY > windowH) {
      // Set class on scrolling down
      header.classList.add("is-fixed");
      // Determine ready to animate
      if (windowY > windowH + 0) {
        header.classList.add("can-animate");
        if (windowY < lastScroll) {
          // Determine scrolling up
          header.classList.add("scroll-up");
          main.classList.remove("move-sidenav"); // for side nav
        } else {
          header.classList.remove("scroll-up");
          main.classList.add("move-sidenav"); // for side nav
        }
      } else {
        header.classList.remove("scroll-up");
        main.classList.add("move-sidenav"); // for side nav
      }
    } else {
      header.classList.remove("is-fixed", "can-animate");
      main.classList.remove("move-sidenav"); // for side nav
    }
    lastScroll = windowY;
  };
  window.addEventListener("scroll", throttle(validateHeader, 100));
```

Comment: You had this tagged a jquery but there is none in there so I changed it to javascript

Comment: Perhaps update that html/code to instantiate some kind of scroll/visual and CSS to indicate that? As it stands 4 rows of HTML text does not really scroll.  I made a snippet of the code to perhaps make updates/test usage easier

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, if you want #main to get **scroll-down** when header gets **is-fixed**, cant you just add it to the classlist of main below the line **header.classList.add("is-fixed");** ?? That is when the header is getting the class.

Comment: Face plant. I totally overlooked that imvain2. And sorry for the lack of posted code... the interaction/page I'm creating is extremely long and too complex to post here. I was writing another script that watches header for a class, but simpler solutions are always the better ones!!